# How to join 2 data frame based on complex conditions

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, join

I have 2 data frames:

A :

```
+----------+------+-------------+-------------+
|title     |name  |product      |available    |
+----------+------+-------------+-------------+
|AAAAA     |WW    |indoor camera|true         |
|A121AA    |AA    |indoor camera|true         |
|AACCCA    |YY    |indoor camera|true         |
+----------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

B :

```
+-------------+----------+-------------------+
| product     | title    | name              |
+-------------+----------+-------------------+
|indoor camera|FFFFF     |WW                 |
|indoor camera|F1FFF     |WW                 |
|indoor camera|FYFFF     |YY                 |
|indoor camera|BBB       |MNMN               |
|indoor camera|CCC       |MNMN               |
|indoor camera|DDD       |BBBNNN             |
+-------------+----------+-------------------+
```

I need to get a joined data that looks like :

```
+----------+------+-------------+-------------+
|title     |name  |product      |available    |
+----------+------+-------------+-------------+
|AAAAA     |WW    |indoor camera|true         |
|AACCCA    |YY    |indoor camera|true         |
|A121AA    |AA    |indoor camera|true         |
|BBB       |MNMN  |indoor camera|null         |
|CCC       |MNMN  |indoor camera|null         |
|DDD       |BBBNNN|indoor camera|null         |
+----------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

I would like to join based on "product" and get the joined data. If the "name" is in A then the final joined data should have the title from A(only eg WW) for that name and get rest from B. I am not sure what kind of join I need for this. Can some one suggest me any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use full join

```
a.join(b, ['title'], how='full').show()
```

Or coalesce the two table columns

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
a.join(b, a.title == b.title , how='full').select(
    F.coalesce(a.title , b.title ).alias('title'), a.name , a.product,a.available
).show()
```

Comment: Little confused here. I thought coalesce is to repartition. Am I wrong ? Care to explain your logic

Comment: coalesce is not for partition, it is working like if there column value is null then it will consider the 2nd one. so when you full join with title you'll find unmatching row ans that time it will consider both values of two tables @user3407267

Comment: But it is not removing the other rows

Comment: "true" for all values

Comment: @user3407267, you can check now

Comment: I need to join based on "product" why are you joining here based on "title"

Answer (score 0):

Just to see if I have understood this correctly. 
You want to join the frames on both Product, name and title, but retain only those where the data exists in A.
if so, you cna try:

`a.join(b, on=['product', 'name', 'title'], how='left').show()`

Comment: but I need to get other data from B too. See the example.

Comment: Doing this you get the all the data in B where there is a counterpart matcing ['product', 'name', 'title'] in A. The only thing you don't get is where there is no entry in A,